# What does 血筋 refer to in this extract?

Tags: meaning

> 「ま、あんまり張り切りすぎて怪我はしないようにだがな」
>
> 「……なんだ、何か言いたげだな」
>
> 「なんか、結構ビックリ。アタシが稽古してて、怪我の心配してくれる人なんてあまりいなかったし」
>
> 何を馬鹿な事を……と思ったがそれもそうかと納得する。
>
> 「やはり**血筋**に振り回された様だな？」
>
> 勇者としての**血筋**からか、稽古しても期待されても心配されるような事はないのだろう。

I've looked up and 血筋 seems it can refer to a few things, like that a certain ability or appearance etc is inherited from one's blood relatives, or to refer to relationship between people. What does it refer to in this excerpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「[血筋]{ちすじ}」, in this context, could only mean "(good) lineage".

> 「やはり血筋に[振]{ふ}り[回]{まわ}された[様]{よう}だな？」

would mean:

> "As expected, it seems you had been pushed around because of your lineage."

The woman (I assume it is a woman from the third line) is of such good lineage as a fighter/warrior that people around her take it for granted that she will not get hurt from rigorous training.  They tend to think that she will survive any hardships, so they do not care about her much.